# Hilfsverb von transitiven Verben

Tags: verb, past-participle, auxiliary-verb

Ich bin kein deutscher Muttersprachler und habe lange gedacht, dass kein transitives Verb im Deutschen sein Perfekt mit dem Hilfsverb "sein" bilden kann. Heute habe ich aber [diese Seite](https://blog.leo.org/2021/02/24/bin-oder-habe-ich-den-weg-entlanggelaufen-das-hilfsverb-sein-bei-transitiven-verben/) gesehen, und hier sind schon die Wörter "loswerden", "eingehen", "durchgehen", "entlanggehen" als Ausnahmen angegeben. Jetzt interessiere ich mich, ob es noch solche Verbe gibt — und vielleicht kann man sie sogar an etwas erkennen?
Insbesondere möchte ich wissen, welches Hilfsverb mit dem Wort "ankommen" im Sinne von "ergreifen", "überkommen" benutzt werden soll. Einerseits wird "sein" mit "ankommen" in anderen Bedeutungen verwendet, aber andererseits ist es möglich, dass dieser Fall noch eine Ausnahme ist.

Comment: Kannst Du ein Beispiel für „ankommen“ in dieser Bedeutung angeben? Mir ist nicht klar, was Du meinst.

Comment: Das sind allesamt keine Verben, die den höchst hochsprachlichen Register betreffen würden. Daher ist anzunehmen, dass die allgemein formulierte Regel immer gilt. Im Zweifelsfall kommt es auf den Jargon an, hier wohl die Rechtswissenschaft. Die entsprechende Quelle wäre das Deutsche Rechtswörterbuch DRW mit historischen Beispielen scheinbar nur mit "sind" https://drw.hadw-bw.de/drw-cgi/zeige?index=lemmata&term=ankommen

Comment: Just to add: "ankommen" is VERY unusual in this usage. And I mean it. You will probably never hear it used in this meaning.

Comment: @CarstenS "Angst kommt ihn an" — ein Beispiel von Duden https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ankommen

Comment: @ErithreusHoffing Wirklich? Eigentlich ist es Schade, dass ich dies nicht erkennen und mich nur auf Wörterbücher wie Duden und DWDS verlassen kann: Diese Bedeutung ist in beiden als gehoben bezeichnet, aber nicht veraltet. Was denken Sie über die Bedeutungen "bei einem Publikum Anklang finden" (dieser Witz ist gut angekommen) oder "eine Stellung finden" (er ist in diesem Betrieb als Buchhalter angekommen)?

Comment: @aldin Letzteres ist ungewöhnlich. "Eine Stellung finden" habe ich ebenfalls noch nie gehört. Meine Meinung ist aber nicht universell.

Answer (score 2):

Das Erkennungsmerkmal ist ziemlich einfach: Verben, die das Perfekt mit "sein" bilden, tun das auch, wenn sie durch Vorsilben zu transitiven Verben erweitert werden. Also:

- Ich habe das Buch gelesen
- Ich habe den Text *ab*gelesen
- Ich bin nach Hause gegangen
- Ich bin einen Kontrakt *ein*gegangen
- Ich bin fertig geworden
- Ich bin den Kater *los*geworden

(Das Verb "ankommen" im Sinne von "jmd. hart/schwer etc. betreffen" ist heute sehr ungebräuchlich, aber es folgt exakt demselben Prinzip.)

Comment: Also immer tun sie es nicht: *hat schon wieder ein paar Schuhe durchgelaufen, hat ihn körperlich angegangen*. Bei *loswerden* gehört der Akkusativ vielleicht zu *los* (*jemanden los sein*).

Comment: Aber mit "begehen" ist es schon anders.